# toggleClass Jquery not working for child to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add and remove one class(sameCols) to a div(col2set) with button(.org) click.
div col2set is the first div. button(.org) placed inside div'col2set' after multiple divs. if I use only add section code then addclass is working. when I use remove section code then both(add/remove) not working.  toggleClass also not working.  please help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //add
    $(document).on("click", ".org", function () {
        $(this).closest(".col2set").addClass("sameCols");
    });

    //remove
    $(document).on("click", ".sameCols .org", function () {
        $(this).closest(".col2set").removeClass("sameCols");
    });


 });



<section class="data-block col2set">
  <div class="ls">
    <div class="box"  >
      <div class="sm-head">

        <div class="pull-right">
          <label class="switch org">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider round"></span> </label>
          <h5>VIEW ORGINAL CLAIMS</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XNkDx/7880/

Comment: Post the HTML pls..

Comment: Your fiddle does not work because you use jQuery 1.4.4. Just change it to higher version and it works properly.

Comment: And when dubugging js always remember to check the console. If there are any errors try to fix them.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao  HTML added, pls help

Answer (score 3):

Lets take a look at your code

```js
$(document).on("click", ".org", function () {
  $(this).closest(".col2set").addClass("sameCols");
});

$(document).on("click", ".sameCols .org", function () {
  $(this).closest(".col2set").removeClass("sameCols");
});
```

You have here two `click` events bounded to document.

**First event** fires when your `event.taregt` is any element with class `org` and adds `sameCols` class to first parent with class `col2set`

**Second event** fires when your `event.target` is any element with class `org` which is in an element with class `sameCols` and removes class `sameCols` from first parent with `col2set` class.

**So what happens when you click on an `.sameCols .org` element?**

Both events triggers.

*Why?* Why not? First activates on any element with class `org` so it fires. Second activates on any element with class `org` that is inside `.sameCols` element so it also triggers.

*So how to solve this?* Easily, just use `toggleClass()` function. **Here is an working example**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".org", function() {
  $(this).closest(".col2set").toggleClass("sameCols");
});
```

```css
.col2set {
  background: #EEE;
  padding: 5px 8px;
}

.col2set.sameCols {
  background: #ADA;
}

.org {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #DDD;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="col2set">
  Here is some text.
  <div class="org">Click me</div>
</div>
<div class="col2set">
  Here is some text.
  <div class="org">Click me</div>
</div>
<div class="col2set">
  Here is some text.
  <div class="org">Click me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click events overlap, you should do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //add
    $(document).on("click", ".col2set:not('.sameCols').org", function () {
        $(this).closest(".col2set").addClass("sameCols");
    });

    //remove
    $(document).on("click", ".sameCols .org", function () {
        $(this).closest(".col2set").removeClass("sameCols");
    });


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document.body).on("click", ".org", function () {
        $(".col2set").toggleClass("sameCols");
    });
```

Comment: although it can work, that way he's not going to get the `closest()`, it will add/remove the class from all `.col2set`, not just the closest one.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `.sameCols` from `$(document).on("click", ".sameCols .org", function ()`
It should have been like

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //add and remove
    $(document).on("click", ".org", function () {
        $(this).closest(".col2set").toggleClass("sameCols");
    });

 });
```

Comment: it probably won't work, you will have two listeners to click to the same class, which one should be used when you click?

Comment: hanks @CalvinNunes! didn't realize that at first

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this entirely without jQuery very readily:

```
const toggleClassName = "example"

document.querySelectorAll(".org").forEach(el => {
  window.addEventListener(el, () => {
    const parent = el.parentElement;
    if (!parent) return;
    parent.classList.includes(toggleClassName) ? 
      parent.classList.remove(toggleClassName) : 
      parent.classList.add(toggleClassName);
  })
})
```

If you really want to use jQuery, you can at least reduce the number of event handlers to one so your logic is encapsulated instead of being divided across two separate closures:

```
$('.parentClass').on('click', '.org', function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('example');
});
```